# Necesito crear un formulario en codeingniter que al recargar la pagina no me borre los datos anteriormente ingresados

Tags: php, javascript, html, html5, codeigniter

tengo un problema el cual no puedo solucionar. Estoy creando un formulario para cargar productos y cuenta con una opcion que es "Categoria producto", que corresponde a otra tabla y se elige con un Select, en el caso de que la categoria no exista, hay un boton que abre un modal y te permite crear una categoria, ahi aparece el problema, al crear la categoria se redirecciona a la vista de crear producto y me borra todos los datos cargados anteriormente lo que vuelve un poco molesto a la hora de cargar. Les adjunto una parte del codigo para guiar un poco sobre mi problema a modo ilustracion, desde ya muchas gracias. Espero una respuesta!

```
<FORM id="form" class="form-horizontal" name="form" action="<?=base_url()?>Controlador_productos/crear_producto" method="POST">


<label class="control-label">EAN</label>   <input class="form-control" type="text" name="ean_producto" placeholder="Codigo de barra" required>   <label class="control-label">Categoria producto</label>
    <select>
      <option>Golosinas</option>
      <option>Bebidas</option>
      <option>Cigarrillos</option>
    </select>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalCategoria">Crear Categoria</button>
  <label class="control-label">Nombre producto</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="nombre_producto" placeholder="Galletas de agua" required>
</FORM>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="ModalCategoria" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title" align="center">Nueva categoria</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                        <form id="form" name="form" action="<?=base_url()?>Controlador_productos/nueva_categoria" method="POST">
                             <h5 align="center">Nombre</h5>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" style="" name="nombre_categoria_producto" required="">
                </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block" name="guardar" id="guardar" value="Guardar">Guardar</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                        </form>
          </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: El formulario del modal tendrías que enviarlo por AJAX y una vez que se crea la categoría actualizar el select anterior.

Answer (score 0):

En este caso puedes utilizar Ajax para enviar el registro de la categoría y también para desplegar las opciones del select. Un ejemplo sería:

```
$('#formCategorias').on('submit', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault(); //con esto previenes que se recargue la pagina
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: $(this).attr("action"), //url donde se va enviar el formulario
        data: $('form').serialize(), //campos del formulario que se envian
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data) //imprimes en consola la respuesta
          $('#modalCategoria').modal('close'); //cierras el modal
          $('#categorias').ajax.reload(); //recargas el select
        }
})
      $('#form')[0].reset(); //limpias el formulario
})
```

Lo que te haría falta es otro ajax donde consultes las categorías y las muestres en el select. De ese modo puedes solucionar tu inconveniente.